# "No se pudo llevar a cabo la implementación" Visual Studio Mac Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, depuración

He estado realizando depuración de una aplicación móvil que estoy desarrollando en Xamarin Android con Visual Studio. Siempre que ejecuto en el dispositivo físico me muestra un mensaje en el celular para permitir instalar la aplicación.

Sin embargo, reciente mente no instala en el dispositivo e indica que hay errores.

[image: No se pudo llevar a cabo la implementación]

Pero cuando lo compilo sin hacer debug compila correctamente y no me muestra ningún error.

[image: Compilación exitosa]

Investigué en este link, pero no ha tenido respuestas aún que funcionen:

[Getting an error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Path1. Xamarin community](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55020/getting-an-error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-path1)

La pila de errores al implementar es la siguiente:

[image: ERROR EN PILA 1]

[image: Error en pila 2]

```
Compilación iniciada a las 16/06/2019 9:54:03 p. m..


Destino _SetLatestTargetFrameworkVersion:
    Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
    Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
Destino _ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
    MonoAndroid Tools: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/
    Android Platform API level: 27
    TargetFrameworkVersion: v8.1
    Android NDK: /
    Android SDK: /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/
    Android SDK Build Tools: /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/27.0.3/
    Java SDK: /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25/
Destino _GetPrimaryCpuAbi:
    _PrimaryCpuAbi=arm64-v8a
Destino _CheckInstantRunCondition:
    Dex Fast Deployment Enabled: False
Destino _SetupApplicationJavaClass:
    Application Java class: android.app.Application
Destino _ValidateAndroidPackageProperties:
      PackageName: [PACKAGE NAME]
Destino _XamarinAndroidBuildAarRestore:
    Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj/Debug/XbdMerge/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.dll.stamp
    Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj/Debug/XbdMerge/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.dll.stamp
    Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj/Debug/XbdMerge/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.dll.stamp
    Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj/Debug/XbdMerge/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision.Common.dll.stamp
    Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj/Debug/XbdMerge/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision.dll.stamp
    Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj/Debug/XbdMerge/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity.dll.stamp
Destino _ResolveLibraryProjectImports:
  Se omitirá el destino "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" porque todos los archivos de salida están actualizados respecto a los archivos de entrada.
Compilación iniciada a las 16/06/2019 9:54:03 p. m..
__________________________________________________
Proyecto "/Users/[USER]/Projects/[project path].csproj" (Install destino(s)):

[...]

Destino _ResolveAssemblies:
      Adding assembly reference for [PROJECT], recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for AppIntro, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Cheesebaron.SlidingUpPanel, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for HtmlAgilityPack, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for netstandard, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.Data, recursively...
            Adding assembly reference for System.Transactions, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.ComponentModel.Composition, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.Serialization, recursively...
            Adding assembly reference for System.ServiceModel.Internals, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.Web.Services, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.Xml.Linq, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Java.Interop, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Mono.Android, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Mono.Android.Export, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for mscorlib, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Newtonsoft.Json, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Plugin.Clipboard.Abstractions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Resources.ResourceManager, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Threading.Tasks, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Plugin.Clipboard, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLite-net, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Collections, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.Extensions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Linq.Expressions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Reflection, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Diagnostics.Debug, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Linq, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Threading, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Reflection.Extensions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Globalization, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.core, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Core, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for Mono.Security, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Net.Http, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Numerics, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Numerics.Vectors, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Xml, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Essentials, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for zxing.monoandroid, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for netstandard, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.Data, recursively...
            Adding assembly reference for System.Transactions, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.ComponentModel.Composition, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.Serialization, recursively...
            Adding assembly reference for System.ServiceModel.Internals, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.Web.Services, recursively...
          Adding assembly reference for System.Xml.Linq, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Java.Interop, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Mono.Android, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Mono.Android.Export, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for mscorlib, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Newtonsoft.Json, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Plugin.Clipboard.Abstractions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Resources.ResourceManager, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Threading.Tasks, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Plugin.Clipboard, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLite-net, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Collections, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.Extensions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Linq.Expressions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Reflection, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Diagnostics.Debug, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Linq, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Threading, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Reflection.Extensions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Globalization, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.core, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Core, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for Mono.Security, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Net.Http, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Numerics, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Numerics.Vectors, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Xml, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Essentials, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for zxing.monoandroid, recursively...
[...]

Destino _Upload:
    Detecting installed packages...
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(598,2): error ADB0000:  Deployment failed
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(598,2): error ADB0000: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(598,2): error ADB0000: Parameter name: path1
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(598,2): error ADB0000:   at System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2, System.String path3, System.String path4) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:867 


AndroidDeviceExtensions.GetPackageVersionsAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.Int32 packageApiLevel, System.String packageName, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-1/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:640 

[...]

Compilación terminada del destino "_Upload" en el proyecto "[PROJECT NAME].csproj" -- ERROR.

Compilación del proyecto "[PROJECT NAME].csproj" terminada -- ERROR.

ERROR al compilar.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(598,2): error ADB0000:  Deployment failed
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(598,2): error ADB0000: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(598,2): error ADB0000: Parameter name: path1
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(598,2): error ADB0000:   at System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2, System.String path3, System.String path4) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:867 

(System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-1/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:118 
    0 Advertencia(s)
    2 Errores

Tiempo transcurrido 00:00:00.54

Detecting installed packages


Detecting installed packages
```

Qué puedo hacer en este caso para corregir este error, ya que en el visual studio en Windows no pasa este error depurando con el mismo dispositivo el mismo proyecto.

Comment: Revisé este link https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/12/dotnet-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-path1/ creo que puede estar relacionado, pero nada que ver con Visual Studio

Comment: Esta otra fuente tampoco solucionó mi problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069166/xamarin-forms-errors-adb0000value-cannot-be-null/52157808

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso logré resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

investigué en internet en este link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/

[image: Android SDK Tools version 26.0.1]

> A partir de la versión 26.0.1 de Android SDK Tools, Google ha quitado
>   la compatibilidad con administradores de AVD/SDK existentes en favor
>   de las nuevas herramientas de la CLI (interfaz de la línea de
>   comandos). Debido a este cambio de degradación, ahora se usan
>   administradores de SDK/dispositivos de Xamarin en lugar de
>   administradores de SDK/dispositivos de Google para las Herramientas de
>   Android 26.0.1 y versiones posteriores. Para obtener más información
>   sobre Xamarin SDK Manager, vea Configuración del SDK de Android para
>   Xamarin.Android.

Junto con este link:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/problem-in-starting-xamarin

Tuve la idea de revisar las opciones del SDK en mi VS para MAC. Encontré que el SDK justamente estaba en la versión 26.1.1 y lo que hice fue desinstalarla e instalar la anterior versión 25.2.5

[image: Menu Android SDK Tools]
[image: Instalatar la versión anterior del sdk 25.2.5]